# New table insert if Date field is before the current time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, not-exists

I would like to make table inserts for any record that has a Date field, which is at least `10 minutes` before the `current datetime`. For some reason, my table does not create new insert. Below is example code:

```
If Not Exists (Select * from dbo.Table where RecordName = @RecordName and DateAdd(Minute, 10, GETDATE()) >=1)
Insert Into dbo.Table (RecordName, DateField, Field3, Field4)
Value (@RecordName, GETDATE(), '0','0');
```

FYI I'm using `RecordName` as a parameter. Please help!

Comment: What happens when you simply run the subquery?

Comment: DateAdd(Minute, 10, GETDATE()) >=1 is always true, I think  DateAdd(Minute, -10, GETDATE()) >= DateField does what you're after

Comment: Correction - DateAdd(Minute, 10, GETDATE()) >=1 is always false

Comment: Please tag your dbms.  `SQL` is a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is:

`DateAdd(Minute, 10, GETDATE()) >=1`

You are comparing a `DATETIME` to an `INTEGER`

Seeing now is 11/1/2017 8:27 AM in my time zone, `DateAdd(Minute, 10, GETDATE())` would give you `'11/1/2017 8:37 AM' >= 1`

And 1 as a DATETIME would evaluate to `1900-01-02 00:00:00.000`
`SELECT CAST(1 AS DATETIME)`

So you would be testing for when does not exist that is newer than `1900-01-02 00:00:00.000` which I would assume is unlikely in your dataset.

How to correct to your intent.  you likely have a date/datetime field and if you compare it to

`DATEADD(minute,-10,GETDATE())`

```
If Not Exists (Select * from dbo.Table where RecordName = @RecordName and DateField >= DateAdd(Minute, -10, GETDATE()))
Insert Into dbo.Table (RecordName, DateField, Field3, Field4)
Value (@RecordName, GETDATE(), '0','0');
```

Comment: For the comparison, the datetime field will be converted to an int (basically no. of days since 1900-01-01, and so is always >= 1

Comment: @GarethLyons - no, it's the other way around. `datetime` types have higher [precedence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309(v=sql.110).aspx) so it's the `int` converted to a `datetime`.

Comment: @GarethLyons damien is correct it actually goes the other direction to a datetime due to precedence but in either event the idea is the OP isn't comparing the way he/she believes they are.  Also 1 is 1900-01-02 0 is actually 1900-01-01

Comment: Thank you @Matt! This answered my question perfectly!